# JQuery How when.done works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really struggling with understanding how the when...done jquery event works.  Below is a jsfiddle I created to show what's going on.  I have two javascript functions, Main & subMain. The order of events I'm wanting to see on the results screen are:

```
Main Begin
SubMain Begin
SubMain End
Main End
```

Instead I see:

```
Main Begin
Main End
SubMain Begin
SubMain End
```

So what am I doing wrong? :(

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/Ldm1nomj/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Main();
});

function Main() {
    $('#ajax').append("Main begin").append(['<br/>']);

    var jsonData = {
        "text1": "textData1",
        "text2": "textData2"
    };

    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //do Stuff
                var selected = "selected";

                if (selected.length > 0)
                    $.when(subMain()).done(function() {});
            }
        })
    ).done(function() {});

    $('#ajax').append("Main end").append(['<br/>']);
}

function subMain() {
    $('#ajax').append("subMain begin").append(['<br/>']);
    //do Stuff
    $('#ajax').append("subMain end").append(['<br/>']);
}
```

Comment: `$('#ajax').append("Main end").append(['<br/>']);` should be moved inside the `done` callback. jQuery has a tutorial about promises/deferred objects, you should read that: https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the definition in [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) says about $.when,

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

The asynchronous events inside `when` in your code are `$.ajax` and `$.when` inside ajax success callback function. 
So, $.done will be called only after these two are resolved.

The problem in your code is with your 'Main end' statement. This is how the execution happens in your case :

1. 'Main Begin' gets appended to the '#ajax' first.
2. ajax call happens to the url you have mentioned which is asynchronous.
3. Execution continues as ajax is async i.e the execution context doesn't wait for the ajax call to complete. As the next line after making the ajax call is 'Main end' statement, it is appended next.
4. After the ajax call is successfully resolved, it calls the subMain method appending 'subMain begin' and 'subMain end'.

Hence, to get your code working as expected, move the 'Main end' statement inside the `done` callback function such that it'll be called after all the deferred objects inside `when` are resolved like this :  **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldm1nomj/3/)**

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(....)
).done(function() {
 $('#ajax').append("Main end").append(['<br/>']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your input...the light finally came on. I was thinking that once a 'when...done' event was reached, nothing else got executed until it was finished. But as you have pointed out, only the events inside the done function are deferred, all statements below the 'when...done' do not wait and will fire immediately. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is an asynchronous function. You can set async to false in AJAX but it is deprecated.